# To match time stamp in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In spreadsheet A, I have hourly data corresponding to a particular set of sample numbers (e.g. 1-10). Then I have 7 other data spreadsheets with 7 different time stamps (mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss) format. Out of 7, six spreadsheets have data every 2 minutes and the seventh has data every hour.

My objective is to match corresponding data values of 7 spreadsheets (1-7) with spreadsheet A and calculate the mean value of the data for each set of samples.

I have only basic knowledge of working with excel, so I first created a grand time stamp (called it as GTS, which has data entries every second) and then converted each entry of GTS and other time stamp entries into "serial date" format. I am trying to match these entries using functions like "IF", "Match" etc. but haven't found an appropriate method to execute it correctly.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, i'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say but this is what i imagine,

Sheet 1 is your summary sheet, with column A having the times and data to the right.  and sheets 2-7 with the source data in a similar set up.

1st question do you need all the data in 1 column or can you have 7 columns with the last one being the mean?  if so then

```
=index(Sheet2!B:B,match(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),0)
```

and sheet3 or whatever he sheet name is for the next column 
or you can get creative and have the sheet names in the summary sheet as column headings then you can just do

```
=index(Indirect("B:$1"&"!B:B"),match(A2,Indirect("B:$1"&"!A:A"),0),0)
```

Also if the data isn't available for every time stamp then i'd add this around the formula to return 0s

```
=Iferror(......,0)
```

if you need to do all 6 source sheets in 1 cell then you gotta do some nesting